# The task of timer can not execute when put the timer after the runloop start

Tags: ios

I create a new thread to learn runloop of iOS.
In my subclass of NSThread:

```
@implementation TestThread

-(void)main
{
    NSRunLoop *currentThreadRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self     selector:@selector(handleTimerTask) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [currentThreadRunLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:      [NSDate distantFuture]];
}

-(void) handleTimerTask
{
    NSLog(@"I am in timer task!");
}

@end
```

that will show the message.But when I put the timer after the runloop start, it can not print the message? anyone can help me? thanks.

```
-(void)main
{
    NSRunLoop *currentThreadRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [currentThreadRunLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:    [NSDate distantFuture]];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self      selector:@selector(handleTimerTask) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) handleTimerTask
{
    NSLog(@"I am in timer task!");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple and basic that if you run the runloop of UIApplication it will blocks all operation and also made UI unresponsive

Comment: In your case if you call handleTimerTask before runloop it will work

Comment: thanks,But I think there are no relationship with UI unresponsive.

Comment: Mybe, there are no source in the runloop so the runloop will return immediately??

Comment: Roshan you are right.  the runloop will block itself, so the timer in local thread must be called before runloop.